# Koa doesn't parse 'body' from fetch POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, koa, koa2

Here's the javascript code that request POST data to my server. when I print out the body data, It seems works fine, but Koa doesn't even parse 'body' from the request(using [koa-bodyparser](https://github.com/koajs/bodyparser)). I have no idea why this happens, It literally worked like a week ago.

**Browser**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".mypage_container .btn-block").click(async() => {
        let payload = {
            email: $('#username').val(),
            password: $('#password').val(),
            country: $('#CountriesDropDownList').val(),
            firstname: $('#firstname').val(),
            lastname: $('#lastname').val(),
            gender: checkGender(),
            address1: $('#address1').val(),
            zipcode: $('#zipcode').val(),
            mobile: $('#mobile').val(),
            newsletter: newsLetter()
        }

        let option = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(payload)
        }

        try {
            let res = await fetch('/signup', option)
        } catch (e) {
            console.error("failed to send signup request", e)
        }
    })

})
```

**Server**

```
router.post('/signup', async (ctx, next) => {
    let data = ctx.request.body

    console.log(ctx.request.body, ctx.request) // says undefined on first variable, request info without 'body' from the request.
    try {
        let user = new User(data)
        await user.save()
        ctx.body = data
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
})
```

Comment: Just to make sure, double check that your `app.use(bodyParser())` call from `koa-bodyparser` is above your `app.use(router.routes())`.

Comment: @saadq that was the problem Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `co-body` to parse the posted data:

```
const parse = require('co-body');

router.post('/signup', async (ctx, next) => {
    let data = await parse(ctx);
    console.log(data);
    try {
        let user = new User(data)
        await user.save()
        ctx.body = data
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
})
```

This should work ...

Comment: This does work. But in the fetch() request the content-type is set to `application/json`. Why is the body arriving in Koa seemingly with a different content type?